# How to enable billing for Google cloud storage free quota

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I m a new android app developer, I m still trying out different google cloud APIs.Google provides free quota for cloud storage n datastore, but why do they force us to ENABLE BILLING for FREE quota for cloud storage? Why do I have to have an account with which I will never pay, since I m just trying the APIs with free quota. I dont have any International Debit/Credit card, its not easy to get one here, how do I try cloud storage ( create/edit,delete bucket/object)?
Is there any public bucket or object that I can try for testing app?

Comment: did u even READ the question ?   ridiculous !! there are 2 questions in that

Comment: did you find a solution, without doing the credit card thing?

Comment: You can do that by integrating Firebase and App Engine, read here: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration)
"This allows you to quickly get up and running with Cloud Storage, without having to put in a credit card or enable a billing account. It also allows you to easily share data between Firebase and a Google Cloud Platform project."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credit/Debit cards are used for the purpose of verification , they donot want to encourage users to  randomly create accounts like how its possible in case of Gmail service(since cloud platform services costs more) .There is no other way out , one gotto register with their debit/credit cards to get access , its the same in case of Amazon AWS services too .

Comment: Is there any public bucket or object that I can try for testing app?

Comment: No ..Its not possible to have access to Google Cloud Storage buckets without an associated debit/credit card .. And Please tick mark the answer if you find it appropriate , that would hep others who are facing the same issue .

Comment: AS google cloud api guide says, a public bucket doesnt require any authentication, hence any one can use it, so I thought if there is any public bucket provided by any ...

Comment: Yes , public bucket doesnt need authentication to be able to read files from it . if you have an account of Google Cloud Storage and upload a file into the bucket and make the file public , anybody can access it .. But one cannot upload files unless you have the account created with billing enabled using ones debit/credit card .